# Bootstrap Column in column

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive

This is visual demonstration: [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fDmta.jpg)

I'm trying to put in my laptop column(col-md-8) second column, but when I try, the other one went under the column of the laptop, how can I put a second(col-md-6)column inside a laptop column, and that column laptop still has its full size.

Comment: You will need to share your code

Comment: It's hardly to see what you want to archieve with the image, could you make fiddle and then we can help you easier?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/5jrt314r/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You said you want it responsive so you have to:

- Keep your laptop element aspect ratio the same as the image.
- Have a screen element that will always fill laptop's screen even if laptop image size changes due to it filling parent element.

If I am right you want this:

HTML:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-8  laptop">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-offset-3 col-xs-9 screen">
                This column need to go in laptop screen
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.laptop {
  background: url('http://devel0p.com/damir/wp-content/themes/helium/images/portofolio/macbook.png');
  background-size: 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
 /* Padding will keep element aspect ratio so we always show image in it's original aspect ratio */
  padding-bottom: 89.32%;
}

.screen {
  background: red;
  /* Make sure this element is always the size of the screen */
  padding-bottom: 64%;
}
```

I calculated image aspect ratio to be `89.32~%` by dividing width by height which is respectively `2084px` and `2333px`.

Here is a codepen example http://codepen.io/anon/pen/aNqKZL

**UPDATE**

In the first example `.screen` element would go beyond laptop screen because of it being stretched by it's content. Here is a version that deals with it http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qZxKRo

Comment: Thank you man, you are amazing, this is solution to my problem, thx thx thx

Answer (score 1):

Do you want like this? It's a very short and a messy description you have. So I hope i'm right.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-12">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                Laptop Image
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

"col-md-8 col-sm-12" classes will keep your column content as you like in tablet view+desktop view but when it becomes smaller like smartphone view, it will expand to the column to full width and you will still able to see your stuff inside of the laptop column.

Please read the bootstrap documentation from [here](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-example-mixed). Anything else you want quick google will fix your issues or we're here at stackoverflow to help you out. :)

**Update**

This is what you want isn't it?
https://jsfiddle.net/5jrt314r/2/

Now Whatever goes inside of that `.inside` class will depend on the laptop image size you have. It will automatically horizontally and vertically center based on the `.laptop` class you have.